# Installing extra packages into a git-for-Windows MinGW installation

Tags: windows, git, mingw, mingw64

For most Windows computers I use, I install git for Windows (from https://git-scm.com/downloads) to get a basic set of useful command line tools that I am familiar with from the Linux world (apart from git, it includes bash, sed, awk, find, grep etc.). The tools are based on [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW).

There are a few tools that I miss. For instance Git for Windows includes `unzip`, but `zip` is not included.

Is there a way to install extra MinGW packages/tools into a git-for-windows MinGW installation?

Comment: See this on how to install additional packages....http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: See this on package identification......http://www.mingw.org/PackageIdentificationHOWTO

Comment: Available packages.....https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/